# Typescript type of object whose keys are functions with one generic argument throughout?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

This is really hard to describe in English, so here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
const actions = {

  save: (payload: T): T => {
    return payload;
  },

  delete: (payload: T): void => {
    console.log(payload);
  }

}
```

So you can see there that both functions in this object there is a generic param T.

How can I accomplish this? What's the type of `actions` there that would allow for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
type Actions<T> = {
  save: (payload: T) => T

  delete: (payload: T) => void
}

const actions: Actions<any> = {

  save: (payload) => {
    return payload;
  },

  delete: (payload) => {
    console.log(payload);
  }

}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYGcA8AVAfFAXigG8AoKKdAQwDcIAuKACjCpABtkqATR7ASkL5spclG4R2EYA2asOXXlAFCoNZIm6kAvqLhp0wKFQQoMjeEgOYqqEPiJkx1OoxZtOPQQXxkKFACdpAFcA1Ch5T24AbjFtABpRCgkpGTdIxW9fMQp9DGQpADpOAHN3BS9Yil0dIA)